# How to verify whether the user got the response?

Tags: node.js

In node js i have simple route.

```
app.use('/', function (req, res){

  res.send("Got it");

});
```

Now after a send the response from the server that how can i verify whether the user really got the response ? Is there any possible ways to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js you can listen on the HTTP server's termination events: [http.ServerResponse close event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1) and check `reqest.aborted`.

Comment: For sure, HTTP is based on TCP connection, which does have assurance of delivery. However, as mentioned in the linked article, HTTP also has concept of "proxy". If there is a proxy in play, you can only prove that the response was delivered to the proxy, not whether the original client got the response.

Comment: in that case the proxy act as the client in the http client server model

Comment: That's my point - from the perspective of TCP, the proxy is the client; but from the perspective of being useful to the OP, the user's browser is the client.